# Launch from file when app already open in Universal app

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-10, uwp

I am currently developing a specialized file editor application for the UWP platform. Right now, I have a file association so that a user can click on a file to load it into the app. This loads the file into the "working files" list which allows the user to edit multiple files in a single instance like Visual Studio Code.

Right now, if a user clicks on a file to open it will launch the app and load the file via the `OnFileLaunched` event. But what I also want to do is load a file when a user clicks on a file *and the app is already open* to load it into the program. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [OnActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242330) method.
You can use [OnFileActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated) method to handle event when application is open and file clicked